# How to set existing Id as primary key in HyperJaxb3 Cxf project, (code generation from wsdl)?

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, primary-key, hyperjaxb

I am trying to redifine primary key to existing IDs, but with Apache CXF plugin generation from wsdl file. wsdl file is here - https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClientService.asmx?wsdl

my pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MindBodyCXF</groupId>
  <artifactId>CXFSpring</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CXFSpring Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <cxf.version>2.5.6</cxf.version>
        <hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>
        <hibernate-entitymanager.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
        <hyperjaxb3-ejb.version>0.5.5</hyperjaxb3-ejb.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.3.2</hsqldb.version>
        <hibernate.maven.plugin.version>2.2</hibernate.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache CXF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hyperjaxb3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${hyperjaxb3-ejb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HSQLDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--PostgresSQL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>logkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hisrc.hifaces20</groupId>
            <artifactId>hifaces20-testing</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--String processing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MindBodyCXF</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!--hibernate plugin for ddl creation-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                            <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/hbm2ddl</outputDirectory>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                    <componentProperties>
                        <persistenceunit>integration.mindbody</persistenceunit>
                        <propertyfile>src/test/resources/persistence.properties</propertyfile>
                        <outputfilename>schema.ddl</outputfilename>

                        <drop>true</drop>
                        <create>true</create>
                        <export>true</export>
                        <format>true</format>
                    </componentProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!--cxf plugin for wsdl 2 java-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceRoot>
                   
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                           
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/ClientService.xml</wsdl>

                           
                            <bindingFiles>
                                <!-- JAX-WS bindings -->
                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                               
                            </bindingFiles>
                            <extraargs>
                                <!-- Turns on the hashCode plugin -->
                                <extraarg>-xjc-XhashCode</extraarg>
                                <!-- Turns on the equals plugin -->
                                <extraarg>-xjc-Xequals</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-xjc-XtoString</extraarg>
                                <!-- Turns on the Hyperjaxb3 EJB plugin -->
                                <extraarg>-xjc-Xhyperjaxb3-ejb</extraarg>
                                <!--<extraarg>-xjc-Xinheritance</extraarg>-->
                                <extraarg>-xjc-XfixJAXB1058</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-xjc-enableIntrospection</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                <!--<extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>-->

                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>

                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hyperjaxb3-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${hyperjaxb3-ejb.version}</version>

                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!--to allow hbm generation-->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/wsdl</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>META-INF/persistence.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

My binding.xml is here -

```html
<jaxws:bindings

        xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:hj="http://hyperjaxb3.jvnet.org/ejb/schemas/customizations"
        xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc hj orm"
        xmlns:test="urn:test">



    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/s:schema" >
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" localScoping="toplevel" generateIsSetMethod="false" >
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="s:dateTime"
                           parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                           printMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime" />
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="s:date"
                           parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.parseDate"
                           printMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.printDate" />
            <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
            false
        </jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
        <hj:persistence>
            <hj:default-one-to-many fetch="EAGER"/>

        </hj:persistence>

        <jaxb:bindings node="s:complexType/s:complexContent/s:extension/s:sequence/s:element[@name='Description']">
            <hj:basic>
                <orm:column length="2500"/>
            </hj:basic>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="s:complexType/s:complexContent/s:extension/s:sequence/s:element[@name='Bio']">
            <hj:basic>
                <orm:column length="750"/>
            </hj:basic>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="s:complexType/s:complexContent/s:extension/s:sequence/s:element[@name='ID']">
        <hj:id/>
    </jaxb:bindings>


    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

but chosen IDs wasn't converted to @Id.

How I can change my binding.xml to convert it?

Answer to Aleksei 1 comment:

I have added more general request to cover all needed IDs and validate all results through FindPath Mozilla Extension - only needed element was chosen 
`

```html
<jaxb:bindings node="//s:element[@name='ID']">
            <hj:id/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
```

`

Classes was generated, but when I run 'mvn process-classes' I have received an error:

```html
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to define/override @Id(s) on a subclass: integration.mindbody.Appointment
```

I think It is thrown do to generated Hjid in ArrayOfAppointment and Id in Appointment;

ArrayOfAppointment.java:
`

```html
 @Id
    @Column(name = "HJID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getHjid() {
        return hjid;
    }
```

`

```
Appointment.java:
`
```

```html
 @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", scale = 0)
    public Long getID() {
        return id;
    }
```

```
`

I have such annotations in several places:
`
```

```html
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity = SessionType.class, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
    })
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "SESSIONTYPE_APPOINTMENT_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "SESSIONTYPE_APPOINTMENT_HJID")
    })
    public SessionType getSessionType() {
        return sessionType;
    }
```

`

```
I think this is the reason of an exception.

All code is available here - [bitbucket repository][1] https://bitbucket.org/sergiishapoval/mindbodyintegrationtestproject/src/179b133cf3a730c718de329c694b311347e16984/?at=mindbodyPrototype
```

full stack trace -

```html
Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl failed: [PersistenceUnit: integration.mindbody] Unable to c
onfigure EntityManagerFactory
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl failed: [Pe
rsistenceUnit: integration.mindbody] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: integration.mindbody] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:265)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.configuration.JPAComponentConfiguration.createConfiguration(JPAComponentConfiguration.java:28)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.configuration.AbstractComponentConfiguration.getConfiguration(AbstractComponentConfiguration.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.exporter.Hbm2DDLExporterMojo.doExecute(Hbm2DDLExporterMojo.java:87)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.HibernateExporterMojo.execute(HibernateExporterMojo.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to define/override @Id(s) on a subclass: integration.mindbody.Appointment
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindId(AnnotationBinder.java:1860)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1279)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:754)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1226)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:253)
        ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should actually work, here's [one example from tests](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/cu-one/src/main/resources/schema.xsd#L230-L234).

Theories:

- Customizations are not applied at all.
- `hj:id` is applied to the wrong `ID`. You seem to have several elements matching the XPath expression. Try to be more specific i.e. add the name of the complex type to the XPath expression.
- You have `nillable="true"`. Maybe you get an additional wrapper property generated (`ID` may be a `JAXBContext<Long>` due to `nillable`). So you may actually need to customize the generated property. Here's [an example](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/602378e16d38337d5279f5b190ee503525189e09/ejb/tests/issues/src/main/resources/schema.xsd#L592-L601).

Seeing the generated code may give more hints, consider posting it.

**Disclosure:** I'm the author of Hyperjaxb3.

## [Update](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3-support/issues/2#issuecomment-83322442)

I've just got a successful `mvn clean install`.

The problem is that your XPath `//s:element[@name='ID']` selects several `ID` elements, not just one. It actually selects all the `ID` elements in the schema.

This collides with complex types which inherit from other complex types (for instance, `MBObject`). Parent compex types already have ids (automatically generated) but your customization points to use the `ID` element as id anyway. This causes problems. Looks like HJ3 tries to generate a complex id (via `@IdClass`) but this fails in Hibernate.

The fix is not to override id property in subclasses. This can be achieved in two ways:

- Only customize `ID` elements in non-subclasses (in root classes).
- Customize parent classes with `hj:mapped-subclass`.

I've opted to the last solution and made `MBObject` and `ScheduleItem` mapped superclasses:

https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3-support/blob/master/m/MindBody/src/main/wsdl/binding.xml#L60-L65

Thus classes like `Appointment` become (in JPA sense) root of the hierarchy and the id customization works correctly (mapped supperclasses do not have ids). So I get a successful build (database tests fail but don't break the build).

Comment: I have added more general request to cover all needed IDs and validate all results through FindPath Mozilla Extension - only needed element was chosen 
`        <jaxb:bindings node="//s:element[@name='ID']">
            <hj:id/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
`

Classes was generated, but when I run 'mvn process-classes' I have received an error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to define/override @Id(s) on a subclass: integration.mindbody.Appointment

Comment: I think It is thrown due to generated Hjid in ArrayOfAppointment and Id in Appointment;

ArrayOfAppointment.java:
`   @Id
    @Column(name = "HJID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getHjid() {
        return hjid;
    }`

Comment: Appointment.java:
 `
  @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", scale = 0)
    public Long getID() {
        return id;
    }
 
 `
 
 I have such annotations in several places:
 `  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = SessionType.class, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
    })
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "SESSIONTYPE_APPOINTMENT_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "SESSIONTYPE_APPOINTMENT_HJID")
    })
    public SessionType getSessionType() {
        return sessionType;
    }`

Comment: I think this is the reason of an exception.
 
 All code is available here - https://bitbucket.org/sergiishapoval/mindbodyintegrationtestproject/src/179b133cf3a730c718de329c694b311347e16984/?at=mindbodyPrototype

Comment: wrapper problem (JAXBContext<Long> due to nillable) was fixed by <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.3</version>

Comment: Please PR the test project into https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3-support/m/MindBody. Yes, this might be due to extension.

Comment: I have no access to https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3-support/m/MindBody my page - https://github.com/SergiiShapoval

Comment: @ShapovalSergio It does not exist - yet. Should be created with your pull request. :)

Comment: sorry, how I can do it? I have tryed to push there my branches after "git remote add lexicore  https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3-support/m/MindBody" but I wasn't able to do it.

Comment: @ShapovalSergio http://yangsu.github.io/pull-request-tutorial/ - I still consult this tutorial when I do PR. It's not so straightforward...

Comment: thank you for help and fast responses, hope I have pull requested correctly

Comment: @ShapovalSergio Good job with the PR, I'll take a look now.

Comment: @ShapovalSergio Please file another issue (GitHub closes the PR issue when it is merged) and lets move the support discussion there.